# how can i do NAT tunnel UDP hole punching in java?

Tags: udp, nat

how can i do NAT tunnel UDP hole punching in java?

because of this, the A and B computer behind the different NAT can not receice the UDP packs which they send to each other.....

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a server S with a public IP address. A and B should open a connection to S. This will open an UDP hole in the NAT. Then S can read the NAT translated address/port for A and B. Then S can send back this information to A and B who can start communicating directly on each other's open TCP port.

Comment: so when A and B login to server the server S record both A and B`s NAT ip address and ports to the database... and send A`s to B, B`s to A(the NAT IP and port) from database?... and what the server S do with the subset ip address of thos A, B behind the NAT? and where we use those local area network address such "192.168.0.101" etc?  thank you...

Comment: S does not need to know about A and B's private address behind their NAT (just ignore it).